# JBoss Application Server admin console?

Tags: jboss, jboss-tools

I know that the JBoss Application Server has the JMX-Console as a GUI for administration. My question is, is there a similar admin tool using the command line? Does this tool come with the application server, and can it report on the status of various services under the control of the server?

Answer (score 4):

You might want to have a look at twiddle.sh 'A JMX client to 'twiddle' with a remote JBoss server.'

Answer (score 4):

Jboss just opened a new project: http://www.jboss.org/jopr/ . This is not a command line but a web application with a dashboard.

I think this is what you are looking for.

Comment: I second JOPR, best tool around and very quick and easy to install. In JBoss 5 it's included in the standard distro

Answer (score 1):

Instead of a command line tool, you may want to consider scripting in something like Groovy. For example, this quickie will get you started in testing JMX MBean Attributes in your JBoss server, it performs as well as (or better than) individual twiddle invocations and is quite flexible.

```
import javax.management.*;
import javax.naming.*;
Properties p = new Properties();
p.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, url);
p.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory");
p.put("jnp.disableDiscovery", "true");
ctx = new InitialContext(p);
contexts.put(url, ctx);
mbeanServer = ctx.lookup("/jmx/rmi/RMIAdaptor");
// Lookups here
```

The more salient issue, in my view, which is what will drive what tool you end up with is what you're going to do with the data you collect.

//Nicholas

Answer (score 1):

In JBoss Application Server 7 there is the [Command Line Interface](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/CommandLineInterface).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using JBoss Application Server 6, you can find a command line tool called Twiddle in the *bin* folder of your installation. You can find more information in JBoss wiki: http://community.jboss.org/wiki/Twiddle

Answer (score 0):

Jboss 7 has a new Command Line Utility named [CLI (Command Line Interface)](http://togotutor.com/blog/jboss/jboss-application-server-command-line-utility/)